# Play video on the img click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m trying to play my local video on the image click, but somehow, the video does not play. It shows the video "box", but the video wont play. Any ideas how to make the video play after clicking the image?

Thanks a lot!
**HTML part: Suppose there is video in each img div - for this example, I included only 1 video**

```
<div class="container-gallery" id="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio gallery</h1>
        <div class="wrapper-gallery" id="index-gallery">
            <div class="gallery-img img1">
                <div><a href="#">First image</a></div>
                <video class="hidden" width="1000" controls>
                    <source src="../video/#6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                 </video>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img2">
                <div><a href="#">Second image</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img3">
                <div><a href="#">Third image</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img4">
                <div><a href="#">Fourth image</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img5">
                <div><a href="#">Fifth image</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img6">
                <div><a href="#">Sixth image</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img img7">
                <div><a href="#">Seventh image</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS Part:**

```
.img-window {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 92vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.img-window img {
   max-height: 80vh;
   max-width: 80vw;
   z-index: 1000;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

**Javascript Part**

```
let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-img');
let video = document.querySelector('video');
let getLatestOpenedImg;

if(galleryImages) {
    galleryImages.forEach(function(image, index) {
        image.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            getLatestOpenedImg = index + 1;
            let container = document.body;
            let newVidWindow = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(newVidWindow);
            newVidWindow.setAttribute("class", "img-window");
            newVidWindow.setAttribute("onclick", "closeImg()");

            newVidWindow.appendChild(video);
            video.classList.remove('hidden');
            video.classList.add('show');
            video.play();
        }
    });
}


function closeImg() {
    document.querySelector(".img-window").remove();
}
```

Comment: FYI: `e.preventDefault();` can be removed because there is no native `click` behavior for an image.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue and provide a working answer.

Comment: I might be wrong here but I noticed that you are calling the video element by element name so please try with `video[0].play()`.

Comment: I enclosed HTML + CSS part as well

Comment: I used video.play() only since in this example, I am calling only 1 video appearing in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code unchanged, it seems to be working fine.

Could it be a browser issue that's preventing embedded videos from playing?

```js
let galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-img');
let video = document.querySelector('video');
let getLatestOpenedImg;

if(galleryImages) {
    galleryImages.forEach(function(image, index) {
        image.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            getLatestOpenedImg = index + 1;
            let container = document.body;
            let newVidWindow = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(newVidWindow);
            newVidWindow.setAttribute("class", "img-window");
            newVidWindow.setAttribute("onclick", "closeImg()");

            newVidWindow.appendChild(video);
            video.classList.remove('hidden');
            // not needed
            //video.classList.add('show'); 
            video.play();
        }
    });
}


function closeImg() {
    document.querySelector(".img-window").remove();
}
```

```css
.img-window {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 92vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.img-window img {
   max-height: 80vh;
   max-width: 80vw;
   z-index: 1000;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

/* not needed
.show {
    display: block;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container-gallery" id="portfolio">
  <h1>Portfolio gallery</h1>
  <div class="wrapper-gallery" id="index-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-img img1">
      <div><a href="#">First image</a></div>
      <video class="hidden" width="1000" controls>
        <source
          src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img2">
      <div><a href="#">Second image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img3">
      <div><a href="#">Third image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img4">
      <div><a href="#">Fourth image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img5">
      <div><a href="#">Fifth image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img6">
      <div><a href="#">Sixth image</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-img img7">
      <div><a href="#">Seventh image</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. The video seems ok, I tried some random youtube video link as a test and it still did not work.

Comment: @Victoria - thanks for posting more code. I've updated the answer with the code you supplied, it's also working fine.

Comment: @Victoria Maybe it's an issue with your browser, have you tried running it in different browsers?

Comment: Thanks a lot Terry :) The code looks great. I guess there will be a problem with the video, that I want to play. When I replaced it with the one you included, it worked perfectly :)